# How to Merge two single array into an array object in javascript(es5) or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-5

Here is my first and second array.

```
var category = ["total_employee","total_present"];
var value = [12,10];
```

I want to output like this

```
 var data = [{ category: "total_employe", value: 12 }, {category: "total_present", value: 10}];
```

Comment: and your try ...?

Comment: I tried through different sources but i couldn't get any expected result.

Comment: why not add this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate and create new objects from both arrays as follows:

```js
var category = ["total_employee","total_present"];
var value = [12,10];
console.log(getList(category,value));

function getList(category,value){
     if(!category || !value || category.length != value.length)
          return;
     let res = [];
     for(let i = 0; i < category.length; i++){
          res.push({"category":category[i],"value":value[i]});
     }
     return res;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try:

```js
const categories = ['total_employee', 'total_present'];
const values = [12, 10];

const result = categories.map((category, index) => ({ category, value: values[index] }));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take an object with the wanted keys/values and map the values to the needed objects.

```js
var category = ["total_employee", "total_present"],
    value = [12, 10],
    parts = { category, value },
    result = Object
        .entries(parts)
        .reduce((r, [k, a]) => a.map((v, i) => ({ ...(r[i] || {}), [k]: v })), []);

console.log(result);
```